# Handsaws for very small flooring project

Tags: hand-tools, power-tools, traditional-techniques

Is there one excellent-quality handsaw that does both crosscuts and rip cuts, and, if not, what two handsaws should I buy?  The task is to install either an engineered wood, or possibly hardwood, floor in a small (165 sq ft) room.  Speed is not important but neat, precision cuts is. I am a highly-motivated novice.  If hand-tools are totally inadequate for the job, what is the minimum set of power-tools?

Comment: I agree with the suggestion in the Answer provided by @RobertNubel, that is the exact type of saw I would have recommended if you want just one saw that can do both types of cuts. Note that as a pull saw it cuts on the pull stroke, when the blade is in tension, and it is this that allows the blade to be thinner. But because the steel is so thin care must be exercised in its use to prevent a kink, so go slow and let the saw do the work.

Answer (score 3):

A Japanese-style double-edged pull saw would be perfect. One side is for rip cuts; the other is for cross-cuts. As a bonus, they're flexible enough to also cut your door jambs flush with the new flooring.

[image: Japanese-style double-edged pull saw]